# the minimum clock frequency required to implement chirp on embedded

Tags: chirp

I am planning to implement chirp over nrf52840. Its max clock frequency is 64Mhz.
what is the minimum clock frequency required to implement chirp on microcontroller?
Will it work with 64Mhz core clock of nrf52840?

Answer (score 3):

Chirp is effectively able to run at 64 MHz but be aware it is almost the lowest frequency at which it can run at the moment. This means that you won't be able to have any heavy processing running at the same time when Chirp is listening to receive some data.

If you want to do some quick prototyping, have a look at the [Arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-nano-33-ble-sense-with-headers) which uses the nRF52480 and for which the SDK provide some code samples.

Comment: Yes, I came across BLE sense. But the problem is it uses arduino interface and bootloader with embed os, and I have to use keep the system as close to baremetal as possible

Comment: The github code for STM32F469i Discovery says, it only sends data, and issues section shows some issues with decoding.
Can that board perform both sending and reception of chirp data seamlessly?

Comment: The code for STM32F469i Discovery is not really working because we struggled to get the audio interface working properly but Chirp is definitely working on it if you get some good audio input / ouput.